# How to setup a globally available react variable (also available in the browser console)?

Tags: reactjs

The below code in a component fails since globalVar isn't defined. How to define it? The function needs to be called from outside the component tree

```
componentWillMount(){
 globalVar.callback = (data) => {
    // `this` refers to our react component
    this.setState({...});     
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always append attributes to the window object.
So going window.globalVar will be accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can always declare singleton and import it anywhere you need it.